# PostgreSQL - Language pgplsql does not exist despite running CREATE LANGUAGE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I just tried to create my first plpgsql function. When executing the script, I get

ERROR: language "‘plpgsql’" does not exist

I then run the command CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql; which shows the following error:

ERROR: language "plpgsql" already exists

Commands are being run on the same database.

Regards

Peter

Comment: please post your function's complete code -- I bet there's some typo in it...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

please notice that you have extra characters in your error. Most likely you wrote:

```
create function ... language ‘plpgsql’
```

kind of like mysql quotes things. It's bad syntax. Just make it

```
create function ... language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 22):

use this command:

```
$: createlang -d dbname plpgsql
```